# Designing an NLP API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, nlp

I'm working on [nat-js](https://github.com/erick-fernandes/nat-js) (a NLP toolkit in Javascript) and I'm planning to extend it to process other languages, like English and Spanish; today it process only Portuguese.

With nat-js, when you need a tokenizer, you write something like this:

```
var tkz = new nat.tokenizer();
```

But how could it be done to process other languages? What do you think about this:

```
var nat = new natFactory('pt');
var tkz = new nat.tokenizer();
```

And there is something I've been thinking about: why load the full library if you're are needing only the tokenizer in Portuguese? Can I offer a simple way to load only the required files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't heard of it before but I took at looks at nat-js and it seems like since it was created primarily for Portuguese, you're going to have a lot of flexibility regarding how you want to restructure the library.  I recommend looking at some of the bigger/accepted NLP libraries like CoreNLP, nltk, and openNLP.  They all handle different language tokenizer initialization differently.
Personally I like your approach by starting a factory based on the language.  Maybe one improvement would be something like:

```
var ptnat = new portugueseNatFactory();
var tkz = ptnat.tokenizer();
```

This way, you may be able to separate more of the main library away into smaller per-language tokenizers instead of having some parsing and guessing in the factory class

Comment: I liked this approach. =]